# Secondary DNS unable to resolve

Tags: 14.04, dns

I am running 14.04 LTS

My Primary DNS(192.168.0.10) is able to resolve itself and secondary DNS(192.168.0.11) and the zone. But on the Secondary it's unable to resolve properly with the reply below after nslookup to dns1.

```
;;Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.0.11, trying next server
Server: 192.168.0.10
Address: 192.168.0.10#53

**server can't find dns1: SERVFAIL
```

---

Here are the config on my secondary server:

Under /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1  dns2
```

Under /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
iface eth0 inet static
...
...
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.11 192.168.0.10
dns-search test.co.uk
```

Under /etc/hostname file:

```
dns2
```

Under /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 192.168.0.11
nameserver 192.168.0.10
search test.co.uk
```

Under /etc/bind/named.com.local

```
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
type slave;
notify no;
file "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
masters {192.168.0.10; };
};
```

Comment: is your dns1 configured to allow axfr requests from dns2 ?

Comment: are you refering to allow-transfer {dns2ip;} under the named.conf.local zoning ?

Comment: Yes, that is what i was referring to.

Comment: Yes i had that configured already